# Check which dynamic buttons (input type button) the user has click on server side php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, button

First of all I want to thanks all of you guys for helping every day , answering questions. You have save me a lot of time and I have learn a lot.

I have let's say this buttons on a form.

```
<button type="button" value="Adventurous" name="adv" id="adv">Adventurous</button>
<button type="button" value="Discovery" name="disc" id="disc">Discovery</button>
<button type="button" calue="Easy-going" name="easy" id="easy">Easy-going</button>
```

When the user clicks on a button to specify how he feels in our example I have the follow code on jquery to change the state of the button as checked and change the class (to be shown with different colors etc)

```
$(".tailor_field .tailor_mood_btn button").click(function() {
         var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
         $the_image = $(this).find("img");
        if(checked){
            $(this).removeClass("mood_on");
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
            $the_image.attr("src", templateDir+"/images/btn_on.png");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("mood_on");
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            $the_image.attr("src", templateDir+"/images/btn_off.png");
        }
    });
```

So when the user press submit I want to check on server side (php) which buttons the user clicked ?

Second I would like to insert the buttons dynamically. Ie to have a string on my DB, explode it to an array and loop each element to create the buttons etc.  How I will know what to check if I don't know how many buttons will be and their names from the beginning ? Maybe with sessions (I would like to avoid it if there is another solution)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```js
var checkedButtons = $(".tailor_field .tailor_mood_btn button[checked=true]");

$("form").submit(function() {
  var data = [];
  checkedButtons.each(function(index, element) {
    var name = element.attr('name');
    var value = element.val();
    data[name] = value;
  });

  $.post('file.php', data);
});
```

The data variable is an array with keys as the names of clicked buttons, an values of values of those buttons. Later an ajax request is made to the file that needs this data (file.php) where the data array is available in the superglobal $_POST (ex. `$_POST['adv'] = "Adventurous"`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it with checkboxs in the end but I keep your answer for future project in which I will use this method. In the form I have other elements also. With $.post('file.php', data); the other elements also are posted or only the data array ? Also you said I can take the values like this $_POST['adv'] = "Adventurous". The problem is I don't know the values of the buttons (adventurous etc). So I have to take the data array like ie data = $_POST['data'] right ?

Comment: In this example, whatever you need in file.php you must put in the data variable (other form values also, but you can can use $('form').serialize() function to help you with that). If you don't know the names of buttons, the data var is an array that you can loop through in file.php, and get each key=>value pair. Also, note that this is an AJAX request (asynchronous), so the page won't be refreshed, like it would with a normal form submit. If you're not familiar with AJAX I recommend learning it (it's very easy if you're using jquery http://api.jquery.com/?p=291), it's a great technology!

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response! I am a bit familiar with AJAX but I am learning it at the moment. Thanks a lot for your answers. You were very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is to just use a list of checkboxes. It is what they were made for.

If you want to use the special buttons though, here is one way using the hidden filed as the input, rather than the actual button. I don't know if the element "button" has a checked attibute.

I just used a simple little javascript to change the values of the input, you can adapt your current function. Just notice that I gave the clickable buttons a new id, appending "_button" to the name from your database.

```
<?php

$string = "Adventerous,Discovery,Easy-Going"; /* this is from your database */
$delimiter = ",";
$button_values = explode($delimiter, $string);

?>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function checkbutton(id) {
         var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
         if (val == 0) 
            val = 1;
         else 
            val = 0;

         document.getElementById(id).value = val;
         alert("Clicked: " + id);
}
</script>
<form action="form-catch.php" method="post">
<?php

foreach($button_values as $value) {
    echo '<button type="button" 
                onClick="checkbutton(\''.$value.'\')">'.$value .'</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="'.$value.'" id="'. $value .'" value="0" ><br>';

}

?>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Then on the server, the form will send the button names from the string and the 0 or 1 if that button was checked.

```
<?php 
/* quick form checker to show what was clicked in the other form */
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    echo "<br>    $key : $val";   
?>
```

Even if you do not use the exact code, I hope the concept will get you in the right direction.

1) Send the data as a form input.

2) Loop through whatever was sent over and check for set values.

Comment: Thanks!Yes you are right about the checkboxs. I was avoid them because I want to style them but the:checked pseudo-class in not supported to IE8 but in the end I did it with checkboxs and forget for the moment IE8. I think is easier as you said to handle the data. About your answer. The form has other elements too, not only the buttons so how in the foreach loop how I can seperate them ? ie check the input field if is empty.... do stuff..... take all buttons and print them.

Comment: It is a little confusing. Do you mean separate them when you get a string from the database? In this case, you need some kind of organization in the database, like column of buttons and one of text fields. Read them out in two loops appending the type like `name="button_$value"` But if you mean separate them after the form is submitted? then it is a matter of using the appended string to know what is what on that side. `if (strpos('button',$key) > 0){ `

Comment: Sorry my English are bad. I meant after the form is submitted. You typically take a submitted value like this : $adv =  $_POST['adv']. But what you can do if the values are dynamically inserted so you don't know what value you should ask to take it and do whatever you want. ie '$name = $_POST['name']' but with the buttons how you do it ? '$buttons = $_POST[??]' ?? Thanks!

Comment: The for loop (auick form checker ...) in the example above will read all the posted information into some kind of usable variables. However, if you truly don't know what the button name will be when they are posted, you cannot very easily check them. You will only be able to handle them generically, store them somewhere and look at them later. So, make sure before you put them in a database, that you pass the name and value through a sql attack prevention function. ex: `db_col_button_value = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($val), `

Comment: If you can have some idea what values will be offered as buttons, then you can hard code an array on the processing script, or perhaps query the database to find out what was already entered as buttons and then use that array to see if there are some duplicates. Maybe you are just getting random one word answer to questions, and just want to tally the times the same word was replied. In that case, querying the database is the way. You can add a tally to existing or insert new responses on the fly.